# Is it possible to STOP the 'Upgrade to macOS High Sierra' message that keeps stalking me?

Tags: macos

Every few days or so I keep getting this notification:

[image]

I always click on Details but there is no option to stop this from stalking me again.

And I’ve tried System Preferences > Notifications and nothing there stops it, nor does changing the App Store preferences.

Is there a way to stop this? Please tell me there is and how.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. The safest option is to just move the `OSXNotification.bundle` file from the `/Library/Bundles/` folder. You can do this either by using Terminal or from within the Finder.

**Via Terminal**

To stop notifications via Terminal, follow these steps:

1. Launch the Terminal app (by default it's located in the Utilities folder within your Applications folder)
2. Copy and paste the following command into your Terminal window:

   `sudo mv /Library/Bundles/OSXNotification.bundle ~/Documents/`
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. When prompted, enter your password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again

The above steps are safe. The command at Step 2 simply moves the `OSXNotification.bundle` file from the `the /Library/Bundles/` folder to your Documents folder. This means you can also undo this at any time with these steps:

1. Launch the Terminal app
2. Copy and paste the following command into your Terminal window:

   `sudo mv ~/Documents/OSXNotification.bundle /Library/Bundles/`
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. When prompted, enter your password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again

**Via the Finder**

If you're not comfortable using Terminal, you can do the same thing via the Finder as follows:

1. Make sure you have the Finder active
2. Go to the `Go` menu and select the **Go to Folder** option
3. In the field that appears enter the following path: `/Library/Bundles/`
4. In the window that appears look for the `OSXNotification.bundle` file and move it to your Documents folder (or another folder if you prefer)

**NOTES:**

- You could also delete the file, but moving it will stop these notifications while giving you the flexibility to activate them again in future should you desire.
- The above steps will also work for older versions of macOS / OS X. However, the `/Library/Bundles/` folder no longer exists from macOS High Sierra and beyond.

Answer (score 5):

A blog post titled [How-To Disable macOS High Sierra Upgrade Notifications](https://appletoolbox.com/2018/01/disable-macos-software-update-upgrade-notifications/) on [AppleToolBox](https://appletoolbox.com/) outlines the steps to do so:

> 1. Click on mac OS High Sierra Notifications Details option OR just open Mac App Store
> 2. Choose the Updates Tab from the list of App Store Page options
> 3. In the banner for macOS High Sierra, control-click anywhere inside that banner
> 4. Select Hide Update and bingo, no more notification!
>
> [image]