# Mojave upgrade being suggested on unsupported Mac

Tags: macos, imac, mojave, upgrade, notifications

My mother has a 2008 iMac currently running El Capitan. Every now and then it pops up the notification suggesting that she upgrade to Mojave. But if you actually try to download Mojave from the App Store, it says it's not compatible with this Mac (according to [Mac OS X Compatibility Guide](https://eshop.macsales.com/guides/Mac_OS_X_Compatibility), El Capitan is the latest version for her Mac). Why is it suggesting an upgrade that isn't actually possible, and how can I stop the notifications?

Many web sites, including [Is it possible to STOP the 'Upgrade to macOS High Sierra' message that keeps stalking me?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/320560/is-it-possible-to-stop-the-upgrade-to-macos-high-sierra-message-that-keeps-sta/320562#320562), say to remove `/Library/Bundles/OSXNotification.bundle`. But there's no `/Library/Bundles` folder on her Mac in the first place.

Comment: There are 2 Library folders on her machine. Have you checked them both?  one is in her home directory and the other is on the same level as the Applications folder.

Comment: No, there's no `~/Library/Bundles` folder, either. I also checked `/System/Library`

Comment: I persuaded my old Mac to stop bugging me on this, but I'm trying to remember how.. try App Store, Purchases. Find El Capitan in the list. It should be one of the few that says 'Download' rather than Install or Open. Start it downloading, saying yes to anything it asks. As soon as it's on its way, pause it. Quit App Store, continue as normal; see if it asks about Mojave again.

Comment: @Tetsujin I tried that, it didn't work.