# Turn off adverts for Macos upgrades (while keeping automatic updates)

Tags: software-update, notifications

I'm running MacOS Catalina. I get two kinds of notifications about updating my OS:

- notifications about security updates to Catalina if they couldn't be installed automatically
- reminders to upgrade to MacOS Monterey

The first type of notification is useful - I want to keep Catalina up to date. The second type is not useful for me because I don't want to upgrade to Monterey at this time. These second types of notification are particularly annoying because they can't be dismissed - the only options are "install" or "learn more", which opens a browser window.

I would like to get rid of the second type of notification, without turning off automatic updates to Catalina. Is there a way to do that?

Note that is a related but different issue to [Stop notifying me about Monterey upgrade](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/432115/stop-notifying-me-about-monterey-upgrade), because I'm talking about pop-up notifications rather than a red "1" on the system update icon.

Comment: If you just click on the body of the notification, rather than the option buttons, then that will either dismiss it, or just show you System Preferences > Software Updates so you can see what the update is. I think the only way to d this is to turn off auto-check, and then check manually for updates. What's the reason for not updating to Monterey? There shouldn't be (m)any software limitations.

Comment: @benwiggy I'll try just clicking on the notification next time. But I'd still like to get rid of them entirely - having to open system preferences in the middle of a zoom meeting or watching a movie etc. is stil not desirable. The reason for not upgrading is just that I don't have any need for the new features, and from past experience one thing or another will likely stop working, be it one of the apps I use or some of my own old code. So if nothing's broke I don't wanna fix it.

Comment: If your apps (and code) are up-to-date for Catalina, then nothing should break moving up to Monterey. Keeping the delta of change small is the best way to avoid any problems. The trouble comes when you stay on Catalina for two or three years, and then eventually decide to update to "OS+3". There are of course bug fixes in each new OS (though a cynic would say you're swapping one set of bugs for another...!) I would certainly move up to Monterey, which is now at full maturity, before Ventura comes out -- in a few months.